# How to know if ubuntu is not detecting my nvidia or is a hardware issue?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, hardware-test

I had to taken my laptop (msi GP62MVR) to repair and had an electrical issue. The reparation was successful (or at least that's what I think). I wanted to connect my TV via hdmi and found out that I didn't have the nvidia drivers.

First I checked in "Additional dirvers" and it's blank:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GizHZ.png)

Then I checked ubuntu-drivers devices and shows nothing

If I put nvidia-smi:

```
*NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.*
```

With lspci:

```
*00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 3533 (rev c0)*
```

And lswh:

```
*    description: Notebook
    product: GP62MVR 6RF (16JB.1)
    vendor: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    version: REV:1.0
    serial: 9S716JB42248ZGA000753
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=G sku=16JB.1 uuid=0000488B-4C24-304C-7074-616C00000048   *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: MS-16JB
       vendor: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       version: REV:1.0
       serial: BSS-0123456789
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 1
          version: E16JBIMS.110
          date: 01/16/2018
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 3e
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 3f
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 40
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 41
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 42
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3057MHz
          capacity: 3500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 43
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 24GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: CT16G4SFD8266.C16FD1
             vendor: 859B
             physical id: 0
             serial: E33DD135
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: MSI24D4S7S8MB-8
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 610A0CC6
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 530
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:136 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:df410000-df41ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Dell USB Keyboard
                   vendor: Dell
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 3.01
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=70mA speed=1Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: MSI EPF USB
                   vendor: MSI EPF USB
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 1.10
                   serial: MSI EPF USB
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=2mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: USB2.0-CRW
                   vendor: Generic
                   physical id: c
                   bus info: usb@1:c
                   version: 39.60
                   serial: 20100201396000000
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:df42e000-df42efff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:134 memory:df42d000-df42dfff
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:124 memory:df428000-df429fff memory:df42c000-df42c0ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:df42b000-df42b7ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:120 memory:df300000-df3fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 3165
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 81
                serial: 58:fb:84:20:36:81
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 7265D-29.ucode ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:135 memory:df300000-df301fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:121 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:df200000-df2fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: 10
                serial: 4c:cc:6a:82:b0:34
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:19 memory:df200000-df23ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 memory:df100000-df1fffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:df100000-df107fff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 5.13
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Mouse
                      product: USB Optical Mouse
                      vendor: Genius
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@3:1
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 5.13
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:df000000-df0fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: VIA Technologies, Inc.
                vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: c0
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm pciexpress nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:df000000-df007fff ioport:d010(size=16) ioport:d000(size=16)
              *-nvme0
                   description: NVMe device
                   product: VT6098 SSD NVMe
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0
                   version: 3.003.15
                   serial: S1T7C0I9000322
                   configuration: nqn=nqn.2014.08.org.nvmexpress:11061106S1T7C0I9000322      VT6098 SSD NVMe state=live
                 *-namespace
                      description: NVMe namespace
                      physical id: 1
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                      size: 477GiB (512GB)
                      capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                      configuration: guid=6b387fd2-88a6-4864-bc63-6a7516172b8f logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-volume:0
                         description: EXT4 volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 1
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p1
                         logical name: /
                         version: 1.0
                         serial: efdda725-0527-4be0-8d40-b51302c8c161
                         size: 104GiB
                         capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                         configuration: created=2022-02-03 11:32:27 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2022-02-14 15:32:29 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2022-02-14 14:48:13 state=mounted
                    *-volume:1
                         description: EXT4 volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 2
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
                         logical name: /home
                         version: 1.0
                         serial: fbfb2434-31ae-4cd0-bd55-b8f194ff2c57
                         size: 353GiB
                         capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                         configuration: created=2022-02-03 11:32:43 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home modified=2022-02-14 15:32:30 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2022-02-14 15:32:30 state=mounted
                    *-volume:2
                         description: Linux swap volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 3
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p3
                         version: 1
                         serial: c88e281e-541c-4c6f-8ba1-47ac6ee973b8
                         size: 16GiB
                         capacity: 16GiB
                         capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                         configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
                    *-volume:3
                         description: Windows FAT volume
                         vendor: mkfs.fat
                         physical id: 4
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p4
                         logical name: /boot/efi
                         version: FAT32
                         serial: 7794-9860
                         size: 1892MiB
                         capacity: 1905MiB
                         capabilities: boot fat initialized
                         configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:df424000-df427fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:137 memory:df420000-df423fff memory:df400000-df40ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:df42a000-df42a0ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 0
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device SYN1509
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device MSI0007
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi
          physical id: b
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WDS100T2G0A-
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0400
             serial: 212508A00083
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=42b3d8d0-c939-402d-9e28-5dd03d284e2f logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /datos
                version: 1.0
                serial: 2fe4bda1-7288-40ef-9d15-bf57a1c7e835
                size: 931GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2022-02-11 18:59:11 filesystem=ext4 label=datos lastmountpoint=/datos modified=2022-02-14 15:32:30 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2022-02-14 15:32:30 state=mounted   *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
*
```

I tried to check if with an live usb it would change and it's the same.

So, my question is, how can I figure out if is a hardware or software issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Check UEFI ("BIOS") as it may have a setting to enable/disable the dGPU.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I can swith to LEGACY instead of UEFI but nothing changes, and there are no options to enable or disable the GPU

Comment: I didn't told you anything about legacy, that would be dumb. ALWAYS use UEFI mode for any hardware from the last 10 years. Now, if you don't have the setting I actually mentioned then we have to conclude the repair was NOT successful. They may have disconnected the Nvidia card or fried it completely because it isn't being detected at all. Another very unlikely hypotheses is they installed some firmware that isn't for this model and it disabled the dGPU. Either way you should go back to the store.

Comment: Thanks, that was my fear. :(